# Delegates, Events and interrelation

Tags: events, delegates

Can someone explain in detail with a simple test program on what is mean by Delegate, Events separately and then explain on how both are inter related to each other? I learned in many books but not feeling comfortable with topics as of now. Any reference videos are also fine.

Comment: See if https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Events helps you.

Comment: Let me try!!! Thanks.